# how to change the default settings for chatter email notifications

Tags: email, chatter, administration, configuration, notification

In my Salesforce org, each users' default frequency for email notification for Chatter groups is set to daily and I need to change this to "on each post". This can be done individually, however I would like to be able to change this for several users in one go. Additionally, I need to change the email notification settings for certain groups to "email on each post", is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do this using a dataloader update on the user object, I'm pretty sure the field you want is "DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency" with the options:

- Email on each post
- Daily digests
- Weekly digests
- Never

Comment: P for Email every Post
D for Daily
W for Weekly Digest
N for Never

Comment: @Girbot what about Default to disable User.UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail (Receives Emails) is there a way?